# Jquery serialize() is empty

Tags: jquery, ajax

I've a contact form that sends data to a PHP script via AJAX. It's pretty basic but I can't get input values with serialize. The form id is correct, i obtain the input name but not their values. Here's my code. Thanks !

```js
 //Contact form AJAX
    var form = $('#contact-form');
    var formMessages = $('#form-messages');
    // Serialize the form data.
 var formData = $(form).serialize();
 console.log($(form).serialize());
    // Set up an event listener for the contact form.
 $(form).submit(function(event) {
     // Stop the browser from submitting the form.
     event.preventDefault();
  // Submit the form using AJAX.
  $.ajax({
   type: 'POST',
   url: $(form).attr('action'),
   data: formData
  })
  .done(function(response) {
   // Make sure that the formMessages div has the 'success' class.
   $(formMessages).hide().fadeIn();
   $(formMessages).removeClass('error');
   $(formMessages).addClass('success');

   // Set the message text.
   $(formMessages).text(response);

   // Clear the form.
   $('#form_name').val('');
   $('#form_email').val('');
   $('#form_message').val('');
  })
  .fail(function(data) {
   // Make sure that the formMessages div has the 'error' class.
   $(formMessages).hide().fadeIn();
   $(formMessages).removeClass('success');
   $(formMessages).addClass('error');

   // Set the message text.
   if (data.responseText !== '') {
    $(formMessages).text(data.responseText);
   } else {
    $(formMessages).text("Something went wrong.");
   }
  });
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="contact-form" class="col-md-12" method="post">
                        <h1>Contact</h1>
                        <fieldset class="form-group">
                            <input type="text" id="form_name" name="form_name" class="form-control" placeholder="Your name">
                        </fieldset>
                        <fieldset class="form-group">
                            <input type="email" id="form_email" name="form_email" class="form-control" placeholder="Your email" required>
                        </fieldset>
                            <fieldset class="form-group">
                        <textarea class="form-control" id="form_message" name="form_message" rows="3" placeholder="Your message" required></textarea>
                        </fieldset>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Send</button>                     
                    </form>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/huja5pru/2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Use serialize() method when form is submit.

check this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/6o6htoh1/1/
```

Comment: Well. It makes sense. Thanks, it works perfectly when I serialize my data only when the form has been submitted.

Answer (score 0):

You have a syntax mistake when you use the jquery selector to a jquery object, when you select your form you must use it lately like this:

```
var form = $('#contact-form'); //and then use it directly in the ajax call like this
form.serialize(); // not $(form).serialize()
```

Here is your fiddle updated https://jsfiddle.net/ingemi/kbpnmptw/ you must use serialize directly in the ajax call

Comment: Got it, I changed the syntax. Thanks for the tip !

Comment: I'm glad it help you, gl